# Flag values in plot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, histogram, density-plot

I have a dot plot as below for my data that I created using the `TeachingDemos` package. I would like to plot some data points in a different colour. These are marked by a * below.
Sitbu already answer to this part but now I would like to flag that points in density plot and hist plot?

input:

```
a1<- c(0.2,0.3,0.5)
a2<-c(1,0.9,0.7)
a3<-c(0.8,0.1,0.12)
a4<-c(0.4,2,0.33)
a<-cbind(a1,a2,a3,a4)
a
     a1  a2   a3   a4
[1,] 0.2 1.0* 0.80 0.40
[2,] 0.3 0.9* 0.10 2.00*
[3,] 0.5 0.7 0.12 0.33

dots(a)
```

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cm2ad.png)

I want a plot like this:
[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKlty.png)

Also, I would like to flag that points in density plot and hist plot?

```
density(a)

hist(a)
lines(d, col="red")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are using the `dots()` function from the package TeachingDemos. Looking at it's source code, I can reproduce your first plot as follows:

```
x <- a
y <- as.vector(table(x))
plot(x, y, ylab = "Count")
```

[image]

The trick is now, to pick the points that should be red from x and set their colour to red. This can be done by first creating a vector that contains `"black"` for each dot, and then overwrite some of the by `"red"`:

```
dot_col <- rep("black", length(a))
red_x <- c(1.0, 0.9, 2.00)
dot_col[match(red_x, x)] <- "red"
plot(x, y, col = dot_col, ylab = "Count")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Stibu. Also, I would like to flag that points in density plot and hist plot? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided the code you used to create your plots, but in general you can use the `col` argument in plot to change the colors of points. By setting col to a vector of color values you can change the color of each point in a plot.